# Elasticsearch query to get the list of documents with some minimum occurrence of a property

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have a index with documents like this

```
[
 {
   "customer_id" : "123",
   "country": "USA",
   "department": "IT",
   "creation_date" : "2021-06-23"
   ...
 },
 {
   "customer_id" : "123",
   "country": "USA",
   "department": "IT",
   "creation_date" : "2021-06-24"
   ...
 },
 {
   "customer_id" : "345",
   "country": "USA",
   "department": "IT",
   "creation_date" : "2021-06-25"
   ...
 }
]
```

I want to get the list of all documents from specific country e.g USA, between a give time range with at least 2 occurrences of same customer_id.
With the above data, it should return

```
[
 {
   "customer_id" : "123",
   "country": "USA",
   "department": "IT",
   "creation_date" : "2021-06-24"
   ...
 }
]
```

Now, I tried the below ES query

```
POST /index_name/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "creation_date": {
              "gte": "2021-06-23",
              "lte": "2021-08-23"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "country": "USA"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "customer_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "customer_id",
        "min_doc_count": 2
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above query returns following result

```
"hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 10000,
      "relation" : "gte"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.5587491,
    "hits" : [...]
    ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "person_agg" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 1,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 1,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "customer_id",
          "doc_count" : 2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

I don't need the list of buckets in response, but only the list of documents satisfying the condition. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of documents, you can use the `top_hits` aggregation, which returns up to 100 documents. The first parameter `size`, in the `terms` aggregation `documents_count`, specifies how many values to return documents for. In `customer_id`, there are 123 and 345, and `size` set to 1 will return only the documents with one of them as a customer_id, it could return 2 documents for 123 or 1 for 345. But, if `min_doc_count` is set to 2, it will return only the 2 documents for customer_id 123. Even increasing `size` to 2 will return the 2 documents for customer_id 123 as there is only 1 document for 345.
`size` in the `top_hits` aggregation is for the maximum number of documents. If there were 50 documents with id 123 and 60 with id 345, and `min_doc_count` is set to 2, and the first `size` in `terms` to 2, the most it can return are 100 documents by setting the second `size` in `top_hits` to 100.
You can try to combine it with the time range filter.

```
POST /index_name/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "documents_count": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "customer_id",
        "min_doc_count": 2,
        "size": 1
      },
      "aggs": {
        "duplicate_documents": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 5
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On a first glance I noticed that in the search query you are searching by a field called `creation_timestamp` but in the mapping of the document you say that the date field you want to range check is called `creation_date`.

I decided to test this locally on `Elasticsearch 7.10` and here are the settings I used

```js
PUT /test-index-v1

PUT /test-index-v1/_mapping
{
        "properties": {
            "customer_id": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "country": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "department": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "creation-date": {
              "type": "date"
            }
        }
}
```

As you can see I'm using `keyword` on the fields so that we can use - sorting, aggregation and etc.

After I created the index I imported the documents you gave as an example

```js
POST /test-index-v1/_doc
 {
   "customer_id" : "345",
   "country": "USA",
   "department": "IT",
   "creation_date" : "2021-06-25"
}

POST /test-index-v1/_doc
 {
   "customer_id" : "123",
   "country": "USA",
   "department": "IT",
   "creation_date" : "2021-06-25"
}

POST /test-index-v1/_doc
 {
   "customer_id" : "123",
   "country": "USA",
   "department": "IT",
   "creation_date" : "2021-06-24"
}
```

Then I executed this search query including a `must match` on the customer_id as well:

```js
POST /test-index-v1/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "creation_date": {
              "gte": "2021-06-23",
              "lte": "2021-08-23"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "country": "USA"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "customer_id": "123"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "customer_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "customer_id",
        "min_doc_count": 2
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This query will return you the search hits as well. Using only an aggregation the searchHits won't be returned.

Here is the response I received:

```js
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.6035349,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test-index-v1",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "vbVD9HsBRVWFAvvZTW-l",
        "_score" : 1.6035349,
        "_source" : {
          "customer_id" : "123",
          "country" : "USA",
          "department" : "IT",
          "creation_date" : "2021-06-25"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test-index-v1",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "vrVD9HsBRVWFAvvZU29q",
        "_score" : 1.6035349,
        "_source" : {
          "customer_id" : "123",
          "country" : "USA",
          "department" : "IT",
          "creation_date" : "2021-06-24"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "customer_agg" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "123",
          "doc_count" : 2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps with your issue. Feel free to leave a comment if you have other questions regarding Elastic! :)

EDIT:

Regarding the grouping by customer_id in a certain date range I used this query:

```js
POST /test-index-v1/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_customer_id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "customer_id"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "dates_between": {
          "filter": {
            "range": {
              "creation_date": {
                "gte": "2020-06-23",
                "lte": "2021-06-24"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the response is:

```js
"aggregations" : {
    "group_by_customer_id" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "123",
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "dates_between" : {
            "doc_count" : 1
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "345",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "dates_between" : {
            "doc_count" : 0
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: thank you for your response. This indeed works. But what I need is the list of customers with min 2 occurrences and I don't have the customer id to use in match query. It is similar to 'GROUP BY' customer id and 'HAVING' count >=2 in SQL. Can you pls suggest?